# How to convert private signing information to Kotlin DSL?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm in the process of migrating to Kotlin DSL. I have followed most of the popular blogs out there to set it up initially. Now it's time to refactor `build.gradle` file. I have private signing information logic as shown below.

```
if (project.hasProperty('propertyfile') && project.hasProperty('key.store')) {

  def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file(project.getProperty('propertyfile'))
  def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
  keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

  signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['key.alias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['key.alias.password']
        storeFile file(project.getProperty('key.store'))
        storePassword keystoreProperties['key.store.password']
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how to convert this part to one equivalent to Kotlin DSL. Looked through related posts and blog around this topic, but couldn't find anything relevant. Could anyone please help me share some thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Please try like below,

```
if (project.hasProperty("propertyfile") && project.hasProperty("key.store")) {
    val keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file(project.properties["propertyfile"])
    val keystoreProperties = Properties()
    keystoreProperties.load(FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

    signingConfigs {
        create("release") {
            keyAlias = keystoreProperties["key.alias"] as String
            keyPassword = keystoreProperties["key.alias.password"] as String
            storeFile = file(project.properties["key.store"])
            storePassword = keystoreProperties["key.store.passord"] as String
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add 
`import java.io.FileInputStream` and `import java.util.Properties`
at the **top** of the file.

Comment: You can also use `keystoreProperties.getProperty("...")` instead of casting.

Comment: what about `v1SigningEnabled true` and `v2SigningEnabled true`?